# Running curl.exe in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl, rest

I am trying to recreate a working curl command in PowerShell 5.1, but when I run it from the script, it errors out. If I pipe out the constructed command to a text file and run it as-is in a command shell it works. I resorted to attempting curl in PowerShell because I have been unable to get the multipart/form-data to work with the Invoke-RestMethod function.  Here is the code I'm using, and the error message is shown below. This is on Windows 10 machine. In a nutshell, this is to upload a zip file to a remote server.

```
$accessToken = '<Bearer token value from prior API call>'
$inputFile   = 'C:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.zip'
$curlCmd     = 'C:\Curl\bin\curl.exe'
$uriImport   = 'https://api.somecompany.com/import'

$curlArgs = '-X', 'POST',
             '--header', '"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"',
             '--header', '"Accept: application/json"', 
             '--header', -join('"Authorization: Bearer ', $accessToken, '"'),
             '--form', -join('"files=@', $inputFile, ';type=application/zip"'),
             -join('"', $uriImport, '"'), '-s'

Write-Host "$curlCmd $cURLargs"
"$curlCmd $curlArgs" | Out-File 'C:\MyFolder\MyFolder2\Curl_Output.txt'

& $curlCmd $curlArgs
```

The error PoSH returns:

```
curl.exe :   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
At C:\CurlTesting.ps1:65 char:9
+         & $curCmd $cURLargs
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (  % Total    % ...  Time  Current:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: multipart
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I have tried constructing the quotes with both single and double, but it still errors out; the Windows command prompt does require double-quotes. When I run this same constructed script from a command window (cmd.exe), it runs and I don't get all of that output nor the error - just the expected value from the API.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the modified, slimmed-down version of the code I got working:**

```
$accessToken = '<Bearer token value from prior API call>'
$inputFile   = 'C:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.zip'
$uriImport   = 'https://api.somecompany.com/import'

curl.exe -X POST `
        --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" `
        --header "Accept: application/json" `
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" `
        --form "filename=@$inputFile;type=application/zip" `
        -s
```

Comment: Ok thanks - I will give that a try. What do you mean by 'pseudo method'? I noticed the example you provided was essentially the same, but with the parens removed?

Comment: @mklement0 They're going to need `(-join '"Authorization: Bearer ', $accessToken, '"')` or similar because the joined string needs to be one element in an array. Without those parentheses the `-join` operator would consume the rest of the array. Of course, they should just use `"Authorization: Bearer $accessToken"` unless `$accessToken` is an array, too.

Comment: James, @BaconBits: I stand corrected: if you use an array _literal_ (an array whose elements are explicitly enumerated) as the RHS of `-join`, you _do_ need parentheses - though for syntactic clarity I suggest putting a _space_ after the `-join`. The original syntax does work (although using an expandable string instead of `-join`, as suggested, is probably better); to demonstrate: `'a', -join ('b', 'c'), 'd'` does result in `'a', 'bc', 'd'`, as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on that guys - I'll need to experiment with the differences in those 2 methods to better understand. Kinda reminds me of trying to remember the differences between $string.Split and $string -split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what process monitor says is running.  It seems ok to me.  I don't have that curl but windows 10 (since 1803) comes with curl.exe now.  Beware the curl alias in ps 5.

```
"C:\windows\system32\curl.exe" -X POST --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer <Bearer token value from prior API call>" --form "files=@C:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.zip;type=application/zip" "https://api.somecompany.com/import" -s
```

I would run it this way.  It's possible that powershell could lose doublequotes to an external command, that you would need to backslash, but this is as much as I can reproduce.  It doesn't look like you're running it in silent mode, "-s".

```
C:\Curl\bin\curl.exe -X POST --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" --form "files=@$inputFile;type=application/zip" $uriImport -s
```

Comment: At first I was using the built-in Win10 curl.exe, but the output was VERY odd. The same error I think, but it's almost like the max column width in the output pane was limited like to around 10 characters - if that. So much so that it was very hard to read. When I downloaded the latest version of curl and tried with that one, I got the same error but it was nicely formatted - I'm not sure why or what the difference is.

Are you saying I need to combine the args on one line and not use splatting? The silent switch is at the tail end of my script I shared, but it seems to be getting ignored.

Comment: Splatting is a hashtable used with powershell cmdlets.  Does it work all on one line like that?  I think it's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I even tried the latest curl inside windows sandbox, and didn't have problems with the code as posted.  How are you running it, by highlighting in the ise?  I see the remote exception.

Comment: I tried splatting the arguments, but it didn't work either - although I don't recall the output it gave atm. I am running this in the ISE, yes. Hoping to get some time to revisit this again tomorrow.

Comment: *Exactly* which version of curl are you using?  Can you give a link to it?

Comment: Sure - here's the link:  https://curl.haxx.se/windows/  - 7.70, 32-bit

Comment: I tried your suggestion of putting everything on one line (broken up with backticks) and it worked! I went back to using the built-in version of curl with this approach, and it worked too. I did not use the call operator though, and I ran it as-is. If I use a variable approach (curl.exe <args> vs $curlCmd <args>) for the curl.exe, it seems to not recognize the arguments. Since I'm expecting a JSON object from this command, I assigned the whole command to a variable and got the output I was expecting. I still got the red error (xfer status) output, but using the -s option took care of that.